# How can I efficiently sort a large array of integers in ascending order?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, programming-languages, large-data

I have a large array of integers containing millions of elements, and I need to sort it in ascending order. However, the standard sorting algorithms like Bubble Sort and Selection Sort are too slow for this large dataset. Can anyone suggest an efficient sorting algorithm or technique that can handle such a large array effectively? Additionally, I would appreciate any implementation examples or code snippets in a popular programming language like Python or Java.

I've tried implementing Bubble Sort and Selection Sort algorithms to sort the large array of integers. However, due to the size of the dataset, these algorithms are taking an extremely long time to complete, which is not practical for my use case. I expected the sorting process to finish within a reasonable time frame, but it's currently impractical for the size of the dataset I'm working with.

I have also explored the possibility of using built-in sorting functions provided by my programming language's standard library, such as sort() in Python or Arrays.sort() in Java. While these functions work well for smaller arrays, they are not optimized for handling large datasets efficiently.

To overcome this issue, I'm seeking advice on alternative sorting algorithms or techniques that are more suitable for sorting large arrays of integers effectively. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, code examples, or pointers in the right direction to efficiently sort such large datasets.

Comment: If Python's `.sort()`/`sorted()` as well as Java's `Arrays.sort()` miss the boat, you are screwed in the general case: They *are* documented to be engineered to be competitive for large inputs (much bigger than biggest cache in the system; but rather small enough not to induce "paging"). If you have extra knowledge about the input such as *small range* or *small set of values* or *small amount of elements not in order (inversions)*, it may be possible to leverage that to achieve a run time that grows more slowly with input size *n* than O(*n*log *n*).

Comment: Have you heard of heap-sort? Quicksort? Radix sort? There's certainly no reason to even consider bubble-sort beyond 1st semester computer science. It has no practical use whatsoever.

Comment: @user207421 I still use bubble sort sometimes because of its simplicity and it requires no array copies as the array can be sorted in place. It's okay for less than 100 elements or so in my opinion unless performance really matters.

Comment: @SimonGoater Have you heard of shell sort? It has all those in-place properties but is far more efficient. Bubble-sort is nothing more than a teaching aid IMO.

Comment: *"While these functions work well for smaller arrays, they are not optimized for handling large datasets efficiently."*: please provide a source for this claim.

Comment: @user207421 I've never used shell sort but it's one to remember where space requirements are very tight. It doesn't beat bubble sort in simplicity though. :)

Comment: @SimonGoater AFAIK, the insertion sort tends to be faster in practice than bubble sort for a small number of items. This is why it is used in introsort (which is implemented in the standard library of C++, .Net, Go and also partially Java recently). CPython uses the timsort algorithm which is known to be competitive with introsort if not faster (but it is complex to implement).

Comment: Sometimes mergesort can be useful if space is at a premium. Part-sorted chunks can be written to disk temporarily and retrieved later.

Comment: "Millions of integers" is not a particularly large data set. The language-supplied sorting methods have no trouble at all with arrays of that size. Have you actually tried them? If you find them inadequate, then post your code and tell us why the built-in sort doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bubble sort and selection sort are known to be very slow for lots of elements, both being O(n^2). Merge sort O(nlog n) is a fast general purpose stable sorting algorithm, with typically log_2(n) passes required, but radix sort O(n) a.k.a. pigeon hole or bucket sort, can be faster, with typically k passes required where k is the key length. Radix sort is not a stable sort though that shouldn't matter if you are only sorting keys. With millions of elements to sort, multi-threading is an option. You can sort subsets, then merge them at the end. If the range of integers to sort is materially less than the number of elements, you could compress the data to (key, frequency) pairs before sorting by key, then uncompress the sorted elements.